# show that infimum is a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

We have a stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and let $B=[0,1]$. Show that
$$\tau=\inf\left\{n \ : \ X_n\in B\right\}$$
is a stopping time.

I know that the minimum of two stopping times is a stopping time but it is the first time with infimum. Firstly, since infimum has not to be attained, I don't even know if we can use, somehow, a formula $\left\{\tau \leq t\right\}$. On the other hand, since $B$ is a finite set, intuitively it seems legit to being 'reduced' to the case with minimum (but only on the intuition level).

Any hints?

Comment: $B$ is not finite. But this doesn't attach your argument.

Comment: Some authors distinguish between "Markov times" and "stopping times" by assuming that the latter are almost surely finite. In this sense your $\tau$ is in general just a Markov time and not a stopping time because it could have positive probability to be infinite (since as you say you could have $\tau=\inf \emptyset = +\infty$). In this case you need only add the requirement that $\{ \tau=\infty \}$ is measurable to your main definition.

Answer (score 3):

What is your definition of stopping time?

For my definition respectivly to the filtration generated by the stochastic process:

For $t\in \Bbb N$ we have $$\{\tau \leq t\} = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^t \{X_n \in B\} \in \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_t) =: \mathcal F_t$$

So $\tau$ is a stopping time.